# Can get PyQGIS 3 map to display in PyQt5 standalone app or menus, but not both

Tags: pyqt5, pyqgis-3

I can run a standalone app but no map shows up, but different from a similar question last year.  The code posted last year works for me after editing QGISHOME to Win 10 system (r'c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis') and path to my data. Similarly I adapted the code for standalone programs from the latest PyQGIS Programmer's Guide and my data shows up fine.  Neither of these examples deal with bringing in a main window from Qt5, leaving me to believe there is a disconnect between Qt5 and PyQGIS that I am unable to bridge.

I built a main window using Qt Designer (Qt5) by following the (Qt4) instructions in geospatialdesktop.com/2009/02/creating_a_standalone_gis_application_1/ tutorial, then added some drop down menus I will attach functions to later.

I edited the tutorial's example code ShapeViewer.py (Qt4, Python 2.x, PyQGIS 2 API) to point to my data and QGIS install.  I had to update code to PyQt5, Python 3.x, PyQGIS3 expectations.

For a couple of days my application would load with all menus dropping down fine, but no content in canvas area.  Then it failed on an unusual error message:  "TypeError: setupGui() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given."  The code (after imports) that creates this error is:

```
gpkgpath = r'c:\tmp\DVD_surveying\NM\geopackages\nm_survey.gpkg'
class geoGcdb(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                                              

  def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)

    self.setupGui(self)
    self.project = QgsProject()

    # Set the title for the app
    self.setWindowTitle("Survey Measurement Exploration and Integration Tools")

    self.add_ogr_layer(gpkgpath+'|layername=filedataset')

  def setupGui(self ):                                                                  
    frame = QFrame(self)                                                                
    self.setCentralWidget(frame)
    #self.grid_layout = QGridLayout(frame)
    self.box_layout = QVBoxLayout(frame)

    self.map_canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
    #self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.map_canvas)
    self.box_layout.addWidget(self.map_canvas)

  def add_ogr_layer(self, path):
    fdslayer = QgsVectorLayer(gpkgpath+'|layername=filedataset', 'file data set', 'ogr')
    if not fdslayer.isValid() :
      print('fdslayer NOT valid!!!')
      exit()
    self.project.addMapLayer(fdslayer)
    self.map_canvas.setExtent(fdslayer.extent())
    self.map_canvas.setLayers([fdslayer])
    self.map_canvas.show()

def main(argv):
  # create Qt application
  app = QApplication(argv)

  # Initialize qgis libraries
  QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgis_prefix, True)
  QgsApplication.initQgis()

  # create main window
  wnd = geoGcdb()
  # Move the app window to upper left
  wnd.move(100,100)
  wnd.show()
  # run!
  retval = app.exec_()

  # exit
  wnd = None
  QgsApplication.exitQgis()
  exit(retval)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main(sys.argv)
```

In desperation I changed "setupGUI(self)" with "setupGUI(self, path)" and an interesting thing happened.  The window appeared with a populated map canvas but no menu items.  I am thrashing here trying to juggle two paradigms and obviously not that fluent in object behavior.  It would help greatly if I had an updated version of ShapeViewer.py and/or an explanation of why my code behaves unkindly.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem for this question.  The source of my problem seemed to be that Qt5 created a python file containing "def setupUi(self, MainWindow):" and my application code, see above, which called this Qt5-generated python file contains a method "def setupGui(self):".  There was some duplication of effort.  I solved the problem by removing duplicate code from setupGui method and some things I lost track of.  Working code below:

```
gpkgpath = r'c:\tmp\DVD_surveying\NM\geopackages\nm_survey.gpkg'
class geoGcdb(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

  def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)

    self.setupUi(self)
    self.setupGui()
    self.project = QgsProject()

    # Set the title for the app
    self.setWindowTitle("Survey Measurement Exploration and Integration Tools")

    self.add_ogr_layer(gpkgpath+'|layername=filedataset')

  def setupGui(self)
    self.map_canvas = QgsMapCanvas()                  
    self.grid_layout = QGridLayout(self.frame)        
    self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.map_canvas)       

  def add_ogr_layer(self, path):
    fdslayer = QgsVectorLayer(gpkgpath+'|layername=filedataset', 'file data set', 'ogr')
    if not fdslayer.isValid() :
      print('fdslayer NOT valid!!!')
      exit()
    self.project.addMapLayer(fdslayer)
    self.map_canvas.setExtent(fdslayer.extent())
    self.map_canvas.setLayers([fdslayer])
    self.map_canvas.show()

def main(argv):
  # create Qt application
  app = QApplication(argv)

  # Initialize qgis libraries
  QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgis_prefix, True)
  QgsApplication.initQgis()

  # create main window
  wnd = geoGcdb()
  # Move the app window to upper left
  wnd.move(100,100)
  wnd.size()
  wnd.show()
  # run!
  retval = app.exec_()

  # exit
  wnd = None
  QgsApplication.exitQgis()
  exit(retval)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: how do you run this application? do you run it from DOS console like `python youprogram.py`? or are you running it in an IDE such as PyCharm?